# I/O Fail of unsigned char typed variable

Tags: c++, file, char, unsigned

I have a file named input.in. I need to read the number and store it in an unsigned char typed variable. I read in the number and print the content of the variable on the screen and I can see it's true(prints 1). However, the if statement fails. It prints False to the stdout. Why does this happen? How can I store this number into an unsigned char variable?

The input.in file:

```
asus@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ cat input.in 
1
```

I work on Ubuntu. sizeof(unsigned char)=1

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    unsigned char ucbuffer;

    fstream in;

    in.open("input.in",ios::binary | ios::in);

    in.read((char*)&ucbuffer,1);

    cout << ucbuffer << endl;
    if (ucbuffer==1) cout << "True" << endl;
    else cout << "False" << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (ucbuffer==1)` is false. The value is `'1'`, not `1`. The numerical value of `'1'` is 49.

Comment: But with the statement in.read((char*)&ucbuffer,1); why is it treating it as a character? Also I opened the file in binary mode.

Comment: It doesn't matter in what mode you opened the file, what matters is what's inside, and inside you have the character '1'. That's what you're reading, and that's what you're getting. If you want it to be converted to a value 1 you need to perform formatted read.